# Confusion about the term "proxy"

Tags: server, proxy

I bumped into this sentence when reading about javascript-promises in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise:

'A Promise is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created.'

The whole term 'proxy' seems very confusing. When searching online you bump into terms like 'javascript-proxy', 'server-proxy'. Are this all the same thing? If not what are the differences?